# Connect to raspberry pi 3 from win10 pc, 2 different networks

Tags: ssh, ethernet, raspberry-pi

I have 2 different networks, my raspberry connect via wifi to network#1 and my pc connected to network#2, can i connect to my raspberry without local connection somehow?

Comment: Are the networks connected to each other?

Comment: No, they not. How can i connect them?

Comment: Port forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your PC has free Ethernet port, you can use a router which has two Ethernet ports connected. One to the PC and the other to the board.

Comment: That's doesn't address the OP's question at all.